# Linq Expressions Parameter Key

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I'm trying to build out an expression to run against an IQueryable of Dictionary

I need to build an expression like such:

```
var test = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
var something = test.Select(x => x["test1"]);
```

I found I can specify part of a parameter like so:

```
var key = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), propval);
expr = Expression.Property(expr, "Item", key);
//results in x => x.Item[propval]
```

How can I create a key search on the lambda object itself? instead of a subproperty.

Comment: Try using [`IndexExpression` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.indexexpression(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: expr = Expression.ArrayAccess(expr, key);  //Throws an exception 'Arguement must be an Array', since expr is type IDictionary<string, object>.  I'm probably using it wrong though :(